# How to create enum of colors (int) from android resource colors.xml

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, enums, colors

I am trying to access xml colors into an enum.
Since I don't have access to context. I am lost on how to access colors from resources.

The colors can be in any form (they can be retrived as an int or color)

So far, I have something like this

```
enum class NotificationType(val color: Int){
    //    DANGER("#F97068"),
    //    WARNING("#D1D646"),
    //    INFO("#BEBEBE"),
    //    SUCCESS("#76D13A")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the int color resources instead of the hex representation:

```
enum class NotificationType(val color: Int) {
    DANGER(R.color.danger), 
    WARNING(R.color.warning), 
    INFO(R.color.info), 
    SUCCESS(R.color.success);
}
```

colors.xml:

```
<resources>
    <color name="danger">#F97068</color>
    <color name="warning">#D1D646</color>
    <color name="info">#BEBEBE</color>
    <color name="success">#76D13A</color>
</resources>
```

UPDATE:

Nice tip by @Tenfour04, you can add a utitlity method to get the color from some enum value:

```
enum class NotificationType(val color: Int) {
    DANGER(R.color.danger),
    WARNING(R.color.warning),
    INFO(R.color.info),
    SUCCESS(R.color.success);

    fun toArgb(context: Context) =
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            context.resources.getColor(color, null)
        else
            context.resources.getColor(color) // Deprecated in API level 23
}
```

Usage:

```
val color = NotificationType.DANGER.toArgb(context)
```

Comment: You can also add a function to the class for retrieving the actual color using Context. `fun toArgb(context: Context) = context.resources.getColor(color)` But I think a better property name would be `colorResId` so it’s less likely to be confused for a color, which is also of the Int type.